# Can a Condition be used to verify the existence of the AssemblyFile attribute of UsingTask?

Tags: deployment, msbuild

Can a `Condition` be used to verify the existence of the `AssemblyFile` attribute of `UsingTask`?

```
<UsingTask 
        TaskName="TransformXml" 
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"
        Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\')"/>

<UsingTask 
        TaskName="TransformXml" 
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"
        Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\')"/>
```

Comment: They usually use $(VisaulStudioVersion) property for this type of thing: by default it is set to the highest available, and can be overwritten from CMD arguments.See details at http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx

Comment: I'm not building in Visual Studio so I think the `$(VisualStudioVersion)` is available.

Comment: Either way, I'm having difficulty getting the Condition to exclude the UsingTask, regardless.

Comment: I am pretty sure, it is. (It's defined in your .csproj file). See details in the link I've provided. The only problem is that sometimes this property is set incorrectly on the build server. To eliminate such a problem I always pass /p:VisualStudioVersion=11 (or 10) in my build scripts when I need a specific version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After testing your code with non-existed paths, I have reproduced your error. Probably condition is evaluated after the task dll is challenged to load.

You can modify your code to get rid of the error by first building the path (either using `$(VisualStudioVersion)` or by hand:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Echo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  

    <PropertyGroup>
        <VSExtPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\</VSExtPath>
        <VSExtPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0')">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\</VSExtPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <UsingTask 
        TaskName="TransformXml" 
        AssemblyFile="$(VSExtPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />

    <Target Name="Echo">
        <Message Text="$(VSExtPath)" />     
        <TransformXml />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

---

Another solution would be to use `$(VisualStudioVersion)` property in the same way ordinary `.csproj` files use it.

You could use $(VisualStudioVersion) to import the appropriate version of the task:

```
<PropertyGroup>

    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask 
        TaskName="TransformXml" 
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
```

As of .net 4.5 the `$(VisualStudioVersion)` property is set by MSBuild  (to the highest available). See details [Sayed Hasimy blog](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx)

Comment: My issue is not related to determining which version of visual studio is installed. My issue is that the Condition is not preventing the UsingTask from being evaluated, which, because the path does not exists, it throws an error.

Comment: @JeremySmith , but you want to use the most up-to-date available version of the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll , righ? So the code I've provided will use v11.0 if it is available, otherwise - use v10.0.

Comment: @JeremySmith , btw, I've just tested *your* original code: conditions work as expected on my machine (i.e. v11.0 is loaded if available, otherwise v10.0 is used, if none is found build breaks when trying to use TransformXml task.

Comment: I've got build agents running on different dev PCs with different versions of studio. On my machine (v10.0) the TransformXml task fails but the error says that it can't find the source in the \v11.0 directory...which makes me think the condition isn't working properly.  You're using v11.0?

Comment: @JeremySmith , I have both. I think I had your code working OK as I've tried to give it non-existed paths in condition statements, rather than imports. Now I've reproduced your problem. I've updated the code to address this problem. NB: the updated property-based code should work fine.  However, you can still use the original $(VisualStudioVersion) -based solution.

Comment: Excellent workaround @Isantipov. Thanks for sticking with it!